# Как получить .app файл из Xamarin GTK# проекта

Tags: mac, mono, xamarin-studio

Операционная система Mac OS (Sierra 10.12.3).
Есть .exe файл созданный при сборке проекта на Xamarin Studio с использованием GTK#. Как получить .app файл, который будет запускаться на Mac OS, где не установлен Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все .NET-приложения (а именно они разрабатываются в Xamarin Studio) запускаются только из среды .NET или Mono Framework. Поэтому - никак!